How do I write double array type?
I have seen this schema:

I want to write this in TypeScript and want to ask is this right?
export type TAllHolidayDataQuery = {
  pageParams: [number];
  pages: [{
    prevOffset: number;
    total: string;
    holidaysData: TAllHolidayData[];
  }]
}

export type Arr = [string] & {
  filter_by_currently: string;
}

export type TAllCacheHolidayData = [[Arr, TAllHolidayDataQuery]];


Does it allow values you want and prevent values you don't? Note https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#arrays

• Screenshots of IDEs are unfortunately not appropriate here. Please replace images of code/logs/errors/tooltips with plaintext versions. • You want to write what in TypeScript? Are you sure you really want tuples here? Or intersections of tuples with objects? What is a "double" array? Please [edit] to clarify the goal here.

From the context, I assume export type Arr = [string] & {filter_by_currently: string;} isn't what you want because it specifies a tuple type with one string element. Try export type Arr  = string[] & {filter_by_currently: string;}

From the image, it seems like the data structure is an array with two main elements:
A tuple where the first element is a string (possibly with additional properties) and the second element is an object.
The object contains an array of pages and pageParams.
Given this, i suggest this adjusted TypeScript Definitions:
    // Define the structure for the pages array
export type TAllHolidayData = {
  // Define the properties of TAllHolidayData based on your specific use case
  id: string;  // Example property
  name: string;  // Example property
  // Add other properties as needed
};

// Define the structure of the query result object
export type TAllHolidayDataQuery = {
  pageParams: number[];  // pageParams is an array of numbers
  pages: Array<{
    prevOffset: number;
    total: string;
    holidaysData: TAllHolidayData[];
  }>;
}

// Define the structure of the first tuple element
export type Arr = [string, {
  filter_by_currently: string;
}];

// Define the overall structure of the data
export type TAllCacheHolidayData = Array<[Arr, TAllHolidayDataQuery]>;

